# How do I make a maven module's generate pass depend on another's compile

Tags: maven, dependencies, code-generation

I have a java module that currently includes a code generator. I plan to split the generator into a separate module. How can I make the depending module use the results of the compiled/tested generator, even if I just run "mvn generate-sources"? Do I have to make the generator into a plugin? Do I have to install the generator into the .m2/repository? Do I have to bump it's version number to force the depending module to regenerate it's code? How does it know to regenerate the generated code?

Comment: Is not having the generator included in the modules listed in the parent pom the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following you completely. If you build (generate-sources) for your original module, which now has the generator as a sub-module, you will get the overall success/failure for the original module and the submodule (the generator).

If you additionally want to run tests on the generated module *at the generate-sources* phase, you'll have to bind the surefire plugin to the generate-sources phase in the pom file of the code generator.

Comment: I want the generator to be built before it is used to generate the sources in the module that uses it. Since they are both (currently) modules in the same parent pom, that doesn't happen. The previous version of the generator is run in the generate-sources phase if I run ./mvn generate-sources, but it should be using the latest version of the generator.